# $F_{\sigma}$-sets of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a function $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Let $N := ${$x \in \mathbb R^n : f $ is not continuous in $x$ }.

Why is $N$ for every $f$ a $F_{\sigma}$-set?

Does it suffice to show that $\overline{A_{2 \epsilon}} \subset A_{\epsilon}$ where $A_{\epsilon} = $ { $x \in  \mathbb R^n \limsup_{y \rightarrow x} |f(y) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon $ }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of points where $f$ is continuous is a $G_{\delta}$ set thus its complement(the sets of discontinuities) will be $F_{\sigma}$

You can find the proof of the fact that the set if continuity points is $G_{\delta}$ in many textbooks or other posts in here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What do you mean by $G_{\delta}$ ?

Comment: @StMan... A countable intersection of open sets

Comment: All right, thank you! :)